# Why is 'scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu' less efficient than 'scipy.linalg.lu' for sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I posted this [question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35266/why-is-scipy-sparse-linalg-spilu-less-efficient-than-scipy-linalg-lu-for-spa) on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com, but received no attention. As long as I get answer in one of them, I will inform in the other.

---

I have a matrix `B` which is sparse and try to utilize a function `scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu` specialized for sparse matrix to factorize `B`. Could you please explain why this function is significantly less efficient than the function `scipy.linalg.lu` for general matrix? Thank you so much!

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
import scipy.sparse.linalg as spla
import time
from scipy import sparse
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
A = np.random.randint(100, size=(10000, 10000))
B = np.triu(A, -100)

start = time.time()
(P, L, U) = la.lu(B)
end = time.time()
print('Time to decompose B with lu =', end - start)

start = time.time()
mtx = spla.spilu(csc_matrix(B))
end = time.time()
print('Time to decompose B with spilu =', end - start)
```

The computation time is

```
Time to decompose B with lu = 4.7765138149261475
Time to decompose B with spilu = 14.165712594985962
```

Comment: Creating the sparse matrix also takes time.

Comment: @hpaulj But I also time the process of factorizing the matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(B==0).sum()
Out[5]: 49510694

B.shape
Out[6]: (10000, 10000)

(B==0).sum()/100000000
Out[7]: 0.49510694
```

Your matrix B is not sparse at all. More than half of the elements in B are non-zeros. Of course spilu would be less efficient when dealing with such a dense matrix.

Comment: I would like to ask if there is any decicated solver for a matrix in which many rows have leading zeros, i.e. many rows are already in upper triangular form.